# aspx.cs (.net version 1.0 legacy) constructor causes message not to appear

Tags: c#, asp.net, debugging, constructor, message

I am working on a legacy .net version 1.0 aspx.cs project for web development.

To debug the code, I use a series of Response.Write statements such as:

```
 string strMessage = "Reached start of method A";
 Response.Write("<script>alert('"+strMessage+"');</script>");
```

These work; however, when I get to a new constructor:

```
 MyObject myObject1 = new MyObject();
```

the message doesn't appear.

It seems unlikely to me (for other reasons) that the constructor would fail here.

Does anyone have any thoughts as to why the message doesn't appear?

Could there be a memory issue?

If I comment out the constructor, the next message does indeed appear.

Comment: can you give as smallest but complete example which we can reproduce

Comment: @Victor:  That's a good thought, but IP rules forbid me to send the project, and making a "skinny" project is probably not in scope for me right now, but thanks -- I do appreciate it.  Has anyone ever encountered similar behavior in a classic aspx.cs project before?

Comment: @Victor:  Actually, this inspires me to make a empty class with constructor and see what happens ... it should be interesting to see whether it succeeds or fails .... results will be forthcoming!

Comment: @Victor:  The empty-class constructor did indeed work; somewhat intriguing!

Comment: @Victor:  your request inspired me to solve the problem, many thanks 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was missing the .net assembly for the relevant project on the relevant server.  So the constructor was indeed "bad" just as the debugging implied!